# YARN AM logs report different time-stamp from what is shown in terminal and sparkscala shell

Tags: java, docker, hadoop, jvm

I am trying to understand why the following occurred:

1. I have a Docker container with Yarn and Spark running fine except that the timestamp of that container was minus X hours of what I wanted it to be. So when I was running `date` it was returning a timestamp minus X hours of the current timestamp.
2. Managed to fix the above by passing a TZ environment variable in the `docker run` command, so when I type `date` I get the correct timestamp.
3. However, when I run `spark-submit` (cluster mode is yarn) applications in YARN, the timestamp in the AM logs is still the wrong one(minus X hours).
4. Managed to fix the above by passing a timezone setting for the JVM in `spark-submit`: `-conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Duser.timezone'`  and `-conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Duser.timezone'` .
5. This tells me that there was an issue with the JVM YARN uses. However when tried to get the datetime from SparkScala shell it was returning the correct time(using `system.currenttimemillis()`) without specifying any JVM settings from step 4.

Questions

1. How can I tell what JVM is being used at container launch from YARN Application Master and what JVM at SparkScala shell?
2. Why are there different timestamps when running in shell/bash and spark-submit ?